# Code breaks syntax highlighting in Atom / Nuclide

Tags: javascript, react-native, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

This Javascript / React Native code, which works just fine, breaks the syntax highlighting in Atom  / Nuclide for anything that comes after it. Is there anything wrong with the code or is it the syntax highlighting engine?

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: "TFN Top Headlines",
    headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "Iowan Old Style" },
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon
        size={35}
        onPress={() => {
          _this.toggleMenu();
        }}
        style={{
          marginLeft: 10
        }}
        name="navicon"
      />
    )
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Is your editor configured for JSX?

Comment: All other JSX in my other files and projects looks fine. How would I know if it is or not?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a Plug-in to support JSX formatting.

You could try https://atom.io/packages/language-babel